# Application Freezes when managing datagridview cells values

Tags: c#, datagridview, freeze

I´m trying to hide a Datagridview password column value by changing cells values to asterisks but it freezes when trying to get cells values, I read that it may be because of the Thread, why?
Early it was working fine with this same code but I erased the datagridview (because I modified its properties and didnt liked) and added a new one.. problems started when I did that.

```
public partial class FormUsers : Form
{
    public FormUsers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FormUsers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadDataGrid();
    }

    private void LoadDataGrid()
    {
        dtgUsers.DataSource = UserHelper.ListUsers();

        if (dtgUsers.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dtgUsers.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dtgUsers.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dtgUsers.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dtgUsers.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            dtgUsers.Columns[4].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dtgUsers.Columns[5].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dtgUsers.Columns[6].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dtgUsers.Columns[7].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dtgUsers.Columns[8].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

            dtgUsers.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
            dtgUsers.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Nombre";
            dtgUsers.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Apellidos";
            dtgUsers.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Genero";
            dtgUsers.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Direccion";
            dtgUsers.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Correo Electronico";
            dtgUsers.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Puesto";
            dtgUsers.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Nombre de Usuario";
            dtgUsers.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Contraseña";

            string pass = "";

            
            for (int i = 0; i < dtgUsers.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                pass = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < dtgUsers.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString().Length; j++) //APPLICATION FREEZES HERE
                {
                    pass += "*";
                }

                dtgUsers.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = pass;
            }
           
            
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to find out where the freeze occurs. I see no reason from the code you show.

Comment: I am in agreement with TaW, I do not see anything in the code that would cause a “freeze/infinite loop.” On the other hand, there is a very good chance for the code to “CRASH”, i.e. throw an exception in the stopping condition. I will assume what you mean by “freeze” is actually a “crash/thrown exception.” I am betting you are getting a `NullReferenceException` specifically from the code… `dtgUsers.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value`. Can you clarify if the code throws an exception? And if it does, what that exception is. As Taw suggest the debugger is your best friend.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, your datagridview is freezing because you are handling the change on the same thread that runs the UI, and also because for every field you are. Although my recommendation would be to set to * the passwords before they even got the chance to be in the datagrid, also saving passwords as a plain text is not a very good idea.

what you should do is replace this: `dtgUsers.DataSource = UserHelper.ListUsers();`

with this:

```
var userList = UserHelper.ListUsers();

userList.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    x.Password = new string('*', x.Password.Length);
});

dtgUsers.DataSource = userList;
```

Password might be another property you have

Comment: I mean no disrespect, however, when you state… _”Yes, your datagridview is freezing because you are handling the change on the same thread that runs the UI,…”_ … ? … This is incorrect. Changing the grid’s cell values in the code using the same thread is perfectly legal and will not cause a problem as you describe. You may want to consider revising your solution.

Comment: When you have a lot of rows, and you update the grid in this way it causes to freeze, it happened to me back when i programmed in winforms, solution would be probably to use async to handle the change. Even so, the Cell he is updating is called "Contraseña" which is spanish for password. Not only my solution will work but it will also be more secure. So i dont see the reason for the downvoting

Comment: If what you say is true, then can you please tell me why… when I copy the OPs code and run it… I do not get any errors and the password text gets set to asterisks? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: _“When you have a lot of rows, and you update the grid in this way it causes to freeze, it happened to me back when i programmed in winforms,…”_ It is unclear when “back when” was, however “today” if you run the OPs code, it will work if you check for the `null` values as I explained. I suggest you copy the code into a new project and set it up to run and then test it. I can assure you it will NOT fail for the reasons you describe. It would be more appropriate to answer using “today's” .Net environment and not some environment you used “back when.” Please test this yourself. Good Luck.

Comment: How many rows do you have? Its true that OPs code may work flawlessly for low amount of rows. But with high amount of rows the performance diminishes, for example is recommended that you dont use autosize, also its better to update the DataSource rather than updating the grid itself. Thats why i stand by my answer, he states the freeze problem is when he is updating with the foreach the grid, thus if that never happens then there is no freeze problem. The freeze is only temporary, when the process finishes it should return to normal

Comment: I ll do a further test, and to answer the back when was 2 years ago with .NET v4.5 framework (Winforms) . Perhaps the problem as you said in his comment is a exception thrown, but OP, is not saying anything about an error thrown by the debugger

Comment: I do not want to argue and I mean no disrespect. You are 100% correct that doing these changes in the data source is a much better approach. In addition, I am confident we can both agree that “none” of this is needed if the password was properly set up in the DB. I would think that the OPs efforts would be better spent in getting the DB set up properly to NOT show passwords in the first place. On top of that, showing the passwords as asterisks in the grid is simply useless from any standpoint. Lastly, since it is unclear “what” the OPs actual issue is, we are not helping them. Have a nice day.

Comment: Agreed, thank you, and its alright. Programming in any language but impossible to master, we are always learning new things. And of course, i wouldnt even be showing the password cells if i were OP. Have a nice day you too